# How can I drag the object menu window?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I'm just starting with blender and I'm trying to find a way to move this window down here. Is there any way of doing that? I tried with multiple mouse buttons but it only toggles between opened and closed.

By the way, what is the name of that window?

[image: menu 3d]

Comment: That's an adjust panel: [Undo & Redo — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation)

Comment: To have a floating window with the same information press F9